# Data Usage For Free eBooks From Google Play Store

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

How much data does it take to download a free eBook via the Google Play Store? It doesn't tell you as you are installing the book. Does it take heaps in general??

Comment: No it does not take heaps of space. Considering its free mostly free ebooks from google play store contains pages lesser than 200. It will be kb's.

Comment: I didn't mean in space. Say if I were using my friend's Mobile Hotspot and I downloaded a book, how much data will it take from him? Or even if I used my personal data to download it, how much data would it take?

Comment: That very much depends on the size of the book (obviously), so a general answer cannot be given. Is the size not shown along? Have you checked with your web browser?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Data Monitor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.andcreate.app.trafficmonitor&hl=en) app from google play store to find per-application basis traffic monitoring. Install this app and check how much data Google Play Book app consumes after downloading the book.

Features:

> Automatic data usage measurement - simply start the app once, and it
>   will automatically measure your data usage from that point on.
>   Whenever you are concerned about your data usage, just open the app to
>   check.
>
> High-precision data usage measurement - the app gives an accurate
>   measurement of your data usage, without any inconsistencies at any
>   moment. Wi-Fi data usage measurements are organized by each SSID.
>
> Easy-to-read statistics screen - measured data usage is separated by
>   Wi-Fi usage and mobile usage and displayed in easy-to-read graphs.
>   Data usage per app can also be displayed, so you can know which apps
>   use the most data.
>
> Transfer speed monitor - a transfer speed monitor can be displayed
>   permanently in the upper-right corner of the screen. Instantly check
>   when and how much data is being transferred.